# Send access rights to remote private queue in another domain

Tags: msmq

How do I assign send access rights to a remote private queue for a machine which is on another domain?

Comment: Ah, do you mean programmatically change permissions on a remote private queue?

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-forest MSMQ? You need to be trusting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx)

["How do I send MSMQ messages between domains?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/14/how-do-i-send-msmq-messages-between-domains.aspx)